# Applying Guice's AOP features to unmanaged objects

Tags: java, aop, guice

I have a Service-Class, that delivers User objects. These User objects have certain relations that I don't want to load initially. My idea was to just add an Interceptor that lazy-loads the relations when needed. Since these User objects aren't known to Guice, obviously that doesn't work.

Now before I completly let got of that idea, is there any way to get Interceptors defined in a Guice-Module to handle Objects that aren't managed by Guice?

Appreciating any answers!

Comment: This looks like a Hibernate and JPA feature, can't you use one of those to load your User objects?

Comment: Unfortunatly, i'm not allowed to use any of those in this project... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, see http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP#Limitations